# React transition group is not working when using a function to out components

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I use a function to out the necessary component based on the state of my app. I tried to use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to add an animation to the transition. But it won't work. Inside my main render, I do this :

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
  {this.signupForm()}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Then inside the signupForm function :

```
signupForm() {
  const {signupType} = this.state;

  if (signupType === 'employer') {
    return (
      <SignupFormEmployerInfo />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <SignupFormEmployeeInfo />
        <SignupFormEmployeeSocialLinks />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My css :

Any idea how to make this work?

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer! React transition group detects change by looking at the `key` of the component. In my example I wasn't using a `key`. So when I change it like this :

```
signupForm() {
  const {signupType} = this.state;

  if (signupType === 'employer') {
    return (
      <div key="1">
        <SignupFormEmployerInfo />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div key="2">
        <SignupFormEmployeeInfo />
        <SignupFormEmployeeSocialLinks />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It starts to work.